# Property value resets when trying to set it in dope sheet

Tags: animation

I'm learning to use Blender, and currently trying to make animations. How I am supposed to change property values of an object? I thought I just I have to add a keyframe on the timeline and then change property value, but when I click away, it resets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the value you should insert another keyframe.

Furthermore, you may be interested in auto-keying. This will make it so that if you change a keyframed value, keyframes will automatically be inserted at the frame where they were manipulated. The button to enable it can be found in the timeline, immediately to the left of the group of buttons at the top where you find the play animation button.